# How to implement Twitter like Tab bar in iOS 5

Tags: ios5, twitter, uitabbar

Current version of Twiiter has a tab bar as shown below.

[image]

When I select a tab , it shows selected tab as pushed (deeper tab).
I want to implement same kind of tab bar in my iphone app for iOS 5.
How can I implement it ? Any knid of help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need create the image with the deeper look yourself and set the `selectionIndicatorImage` property on the `UITabBar`.

It's probably easiest to set this up using the appearance proxy in your AppDelegate:

`[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:yourImage];`

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I did the same thing already & it works as expected.